# Find and print num of solutions to x1+x2+x3=num

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I need to write a **recusive** function that recive an integer `num` and returns the number of solutions to the equation :`x1 + x2 + x3 = num`, where `x1,x2,x3` are numbers between 1-10, the method should print all solutions.

For example if `num=3` then the method will print `1+1+1` and will return `1`.

if `num=5` the method will return `6` and will print:

```
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 3 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
3 + 1 + 1
```

if `num<3` or `num>30` the method will return `0`.

The method should be recursive without using loops. Global variables are not allowed. Lists are also not allowed.

Here my code, it works fine but it also prints duplicates, for `num=5` it prints:

```
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
2 + 1 + 2
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 1 + 3
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("num of solutions: "+solutions(5));

}

public static int solutions(int num) 
{

    if (num < 3 || num > 30)
        return 0;

    return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1);
}
private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3)
{
    if (x1 < 1 || x1 > 10 || x2 < 1 || x2 > 10||x3 < 1 || x3 > 10)
        return 0;
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 > num)
        return 0;       
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num)
    {
        System.out.println(x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3);
        return 1;
    }           
    return solutions(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3) + solutions(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3) + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1);

}
```

> How do I get the desired output without duplicates?

Comment: There's probably an error in your logic somewhere, but a hacky fix is to just use a `Set`. Put each string of `x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3` into the set and check if it exists before printing.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I'm not allowed to use List/Map/Set etc

Comment: You can use ArrayList<int[]> to store the sequences of 3 integers, For every recursive call check whether it already contains that sequence or not.

Comment: @NeelPatel  I'm not allowed to use List/Map/Set etc

Comment: To add more, for example, list as these members in it, List={[1,2,2],[1,1,3]} and now you are getting sequence from a recursive call is [1,2,2] so here using a method of ArrayList.contains([1,2,2]) you can remove the redundancy.

Comment: Ohh sorry, then it's not for use. Let me think I will come up with another way.

Comment: what's acctualy your problem. Finding answers or prevebt duplicated answers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're getting duplicates is that both `solutions(1,2,1)` and `solutions(2,1,1)` will lead you to `2 + 2 + 1`.

The trivial way of not getting duplicate for three digits is count up from 111 to 10,10,10 as if it was a decimal integer:

```
private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3)
{
  if (x1 > 10 || x1 > num)
    return 0;
  if (x2 > 10 || x1+x2 > num)
    return solutions(num, x1+1, 1, 1);
  if (x3 > 10 || x1+x2+x3 > num)
    return solutions(num, x1, x2+1, 1);

  int me = 0;
  if (x1+x2+x3 == num) {
    System.out.printf("%d + %d + %d\n", x1, x2, x3);
    me=1;
  }
  return me + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3+1);
}
```

This mimics your approach of searching through the full space with pruning, but a more efficient solution could just search through `x1` and `x2` and set `x3=num-x1-x2`.

Comment: This is actually a good solution, however it does not work for 28,29 and 30. You should use 10 instead of 9, as the values can be in range from 1-10.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem using string. Declare one global string variable

```
static String str=""; // taken null intially
```

Now, we can use this string str to store the sequence and to check whether it already comes before or not. This way we can keep track of the duplicate one and you will get your answer. I have attached my code as below.

```
private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3)
{
    if (x1 < 1 || x1 > 10 || x2 < 1 || x2 > 10||x3 < 1 || x3 > 10)
        return 0;
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 > num)
        return 0;       
    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num)
    {
        String s= String.valueOf(x1)+"+"+String.valueOf(x2)+"+"+String.valueOf(x2);
        if(!str.contains(s))
        {
            str=str+s+"\n";
            System.out.println(x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3);
            return 1;
        }
    }           
    return solutions(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3) + solutions(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3) + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1);

}
```

Comment: While printing the answer you can use the whole string at the end, I forgot to include that piece of code but I think you will get my point and use it.

Comment: U don't need to use `Integer.valueOf(x1)`. Just `x1`, `x2`, `x3`

Comment: See my post, I wrote **Global variables are not allowed**

Comment: @Antonio112009 thanks for pointing out that error. Actually I wanted to use String.valueOf(x1) but by mistake wrote the Integer.valueOf(x1); I will edit that.

Comment: @Devy I can solve it by passing the string as an argument to our recursive call, this way it will act like a global variable.

Comment: @NeelPatel If you give that a try, you'll see that it doesn't actually work.

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, you are right. It's not working because when we send a string as an argument for each recursive call, all the recursive calls will have the same value for string (not the updated one, in case of global variable it will be done before passing to other recursive calls.) So, we have to figure out how we can pass the updated string value.

Answer (score 0):

Well... no collections, no global variables, no duplicates. I hope you are allowed to use StringBuilder?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println("num of solutions: " + solutions(5, sb));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

public static int solutions(int num, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (num < 3 || num > 30)
        return 0;

    return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1, sb);
}

private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (x1 > 10 || x2 > 10 || x3 > 10) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (x1 + x2 + x3 > num) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num) {
        String str = x1 + " + " + x2 + " + " + x3;
        if (!sb.toString().contains(str)) {
            sb.append(str).append(System.lineSeparator());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return solutions(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3, sb) 
           + solutions(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3, sb) 
           + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1, sb);
}
```

Result:

```
    num of solutions: 6
    3 + 1 + 1
    2 + 2 + 1
    2 + 1 + 2
    1 + 3 + 1
    1 + 2 + 2
    1 + 1 + 3
```

Comment: In the context of the question your StringBuilder looks like a global variable to me. And before you ask storing the solution in the cloud is not allowed either :)

Comment: Great, I thought to use string as a global variable but haven't thought of using StringBuilder. I like your idea.

Comment: @Guillaume I guess instead of using StringBuilder as global variable we can pass new instance of StringBuilder for the recursive call.  Like form the main method instead of sb pass (new StringBuilder("")) with the argument. Is it make sense?

Comment: @Guillaume, may be, it looks like global, but it isn't global.

Comment: @NeelPatel, String is immutable - so any changes in recursive calls will be lost after return.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(solutions(5));
}
public static int solutions(int n) {

    if (n < 3 || n > 30) return 0;
    return solutions(n, n-2, 1, 1, 0);

}

public static int solutions(int n, int x1, int x2, int x3, int solutions) {

    ++solutions;
    System.out.println("Solution found : "+x1 +"+" + x2 + "+" + x3);

    if(x3 == n-2) return solutions;

    if(x2 > 1) {
        return solutions(n, x1, x2-1, x3+1, solutions);
    }

    if(x1 > 1) {
        return solutions(n, x1-1, n-x1, 1, solutions);
    }
    return solutions;
}
```

Output : 6

The idea is the following :

You start with x1 the greatest as possible.

Then you follow these two rules :

if x2 > 1 THEN x2 = x2 - 1 and x3 = x3 + 1

if not, and if x1 > 1 THEN x1 = x1 - 1, x3 = 1 and x2 = the number required to have the correct total.

If none of these two conditions are true, there is no more solutions.

Result :

3 + 1 + 1

First condition false, second true :
We remove 1 to x1, x3 becomes 1 and x2 becomes logically 2

2 + 2 + 1

First condition is true.
We remove 1 to x2 and add 1 to x3

2 + 1 + 2

First condition is false

Second condition is true

1 + 3 + 1

First condition is true

1 + 2 + 2

First condition is true

1 + 1 + 3

First condition is false, second is false.

We have our 6 solutions, so there it is.

Hope that helped !