# Find 3 numbers that are sum up to a given number

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion

I need to create a recursive method that takes a number as input (ranging from 3 to 30, exclusive), and finds all the combinations of adding three natural numbers (ranging from 1 to 10, inclusive) so that they will be equal to this number.

For instance, if the input is `5`, I will need to find all the `6` combinations: `"1+1+3"`, `"1+2+2"`, `"1+3+1"`, `"2+1+2"`, `"2+2+1"` and `"3+1+1"`.

The method should print the options, and give back the number of options. This is my code so far:

```
public static int solutions(int num)
{
    if(num < 3 || num >30)
        return 0;
    return solutions(1,1,1, num);
}

private static int solutions(int x1, int x2, int x3, int num)
{
    if(x1 > 10 || x2 > 10 || x3 > 10)
        return 0;
    if (x1+x2+x3 != num)
    {
        return  solutions(x1 + 1, x2, x3, num)+
                solutions(x1, x2 + 1, x3, num)+
                solutions(x1, x2, x3 + 1, num);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println(x1 + "+" + x2 +"+" + x3);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

this code gives me too many answers (all are right but redundant) e.g. for 5 it give me 9 answers instead of 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that it will have duplicated recursion paths. A straightforward solution is to adapt the algorithm to use a set to avoid the duplicates:

```
public static void solutions(int x1, int x2, int x3, int num, 
                             Set<String> combinations){
       if (x1 + x2 + x3 == num) {
            combinations.add(x1 + "+" + x2 +"+" + x3);
        } else if ( x1 <= num - 2 && x2 <= num - 2 && x3 <= num - 2
                   && x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10 && x3 <= 10
                   && x1 + x2 + x3 < num) {
                  if(x1 < 10) solutions(x1 + 1, x2, x3, num, combinations);
                  if(x2 < 10) solutions(x1, x2 + 1, x3, num, combinations);
                  if(x3 < 10) solutions(x1, x2, x3 + 1, num, combinations);
       }
}
```

However, this solution is kind of slow, because of the number of recursive calls. For instance for:

```
num = 3 -> count = 1 duplicates found 1 Time taken 0.04(s)
num = 4 -> count = 3 duplicates found 3 Time taken 0.0(s)
num = 5 -> count = 6 duplicates found 9 Time taken 0.0(s)
...
num = 10 -> count = 36 duplicates found 2187 Time taken 0.004(s)
...
num = 20 -> count = 63 duplicates found 118569594 Time taken 5.739(s)
...
```

Looking at the number of duplicated found, one can see that there is a fair amount of useless recursive calls that results in overhead. Nevertheless, we can further restrict the number of recursive calls. We only need to call:

```
solutions(x1, x2 + 1, x3, num, combinations);
```

if(x1 <= x2).

Moreover, one does not need to make a recursive call for `x3`, one can deduce its value using the formula `x3 = num - x2 - x1`. So the optimized version would look like the following:

```
public static void solutions(int x1, int x2, int x3, int num, Set<String> combinations){
    if(x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10 && (num - x2 - x1) <= 10) {
        combinations.add(x1 + "+" + x2 + "+" + (num - x2 - x1));
    }
    if ( x1 <= num - 2 && x2 <= num - 2 && x3 <= num - 2 && x1 + x2 + x3 < num) {
        if(x1 < 10) solutions(x1 + 1, x2, x3, num, combinations);
        if(x2 < 10 && x1 <= x2) solutions(x1, x2 + 1, x3, num, combinations);
    }
}
```

the results :

```
num = 3 -> count = 1 duplicates found 0 Time taken 0.045(s)
num = 4 -> count = 3 duplicates found 0 Time taken 0.0(s)
num = 5 -> count = 6 duplicates found 0 Time taken 0.0(s)
...
num = 10 -> count = 36 duplicates found 65 Time taken 0.001(s)
... 
num = 20 -> count = 63 duplicates found 21670 Time taken 0.018(s)
....
```

for `num = 20`, approximately `5471x` less recursive calls. In my machine, it was a reduction from 5.739 to 0.018 seconds. If one finds more expressions that can limit the number of recursive calls, the algorithm would be much faster. Ideally, finding expressions that would reduce the number of duplicates to `0`, and consequently remove the need for the set.

**A *much* better solution:**

After having done a bit of research on the topic, I derived an algorithm (based on the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398612/find-and-print-num-of-solutions-to-x1x2x3-num)) with the aforementioned expression that reduces the number of duplicates to 0, and consequently, removes the need to use a `set`. Basically, I rearranged and changed the expressions of the previous solution and its logic, and applied the optimization of removing the recursive call for `x3`, in order to reduce the overall number of recursive calls, . Namely overall from `16779` to `2007` recursive calls (compared with `328991` from the optimized version with the `set`).
The code looks as follows:

```
private static int solutions2(int x1, int x2, int x3, int num){
        int count = 0;
        if (x2 < Math.min(10, num - x1)) count = solutions2(x1, x2 + 1, 1,num);
        else if (x1 < Math.min(10, num)) count = solutions2(x1 + 1, 1, 1, num);
        if(x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10) {
            int x3_tmp = num - x2 - x1;
            if(0 < x3_tmp && x3_tmp <= 10) {
                System.out.println(x1 + "+" + x2 +"+" + x3);
                return 1 + count;
            }
        }
        return count;
}
```

A running example:

```
class Example {

    private static int solutions(int x1, int x2, int num){
        int count = 0;
        if (x2 < Math.min(10, num - x1)) count = solutions(x1, x2 + 1, num);
        else if (x1 < Math.min(10, num)) count = solutions(x1 + 1, 1, num);
        if(x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10) {
            int x3_tmp = num - x2 - x1;
            if(0 < x3_tmp && x3_tmp <= 10) {
                System.out.println(x1 + "+" + x2 + "+" + x3_tmp);
                return 1 + count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int solutions(int num){
        return (num < 3 || num > 30) ? 0 : solutions(1,1, num);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
            int count = solutions(5);
            System.out.println("Count = " +count);
    }
}
```

you would get the output:

```
3+1+1
2+2+1
2+1+2
1+3+1
1+2+2
1+1+3
Count : 6
```